# Refresh UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

I have created a `subclass` of `UIToolbar`. And setting `toolbar items` from that `class`. On `ViewController`, i took a `toolbar` and assign it a class `subclass` of `UIToolbar`. Its showing `toolbar items` on it.

The problem is that, when i update `toolbar items` its not showing on `viewController`. When i go to another `view` and come to this `view` its showing updated `toolbar items`.

I need an immediate refresh of `toolbar items` on that `viewController`.

Comment: refresh is not possible :)

Comment: iPatel is this still not possible? we are almost 7 years ahead of that question.

Answer (score 4):

In the viewController that contains your `UIToolbar`, call "[self.view setNeedsLayout]" (or even just `[self.toolbar setNeedsLayout]`) to force re-drawing of the graphics context.

On a different note, though: You should not need to subclass UIToolbar to just set the toolbar items. Create a `UIToolbar` and set its `items` array by calling `[self.myToolbar setItems:@[item1, item2, ...]]`